# How do I open the watch faces list on the Wear OS emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

How do I open the watch faces list in the Wear OS emulator in Android Studio?

I am following the codelab [Create a watchface for Wear OS](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/watchface).

I can successfully launch the emulator, the Event Log shows:

```
08:10   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/bquast/AndroidStudioProjects/watchface

08:10   Gradle build finished in 1 s 187 ms

08:10   Launch succeeded
```

I then wake the watch by pressing the back triangle on the emulator. The watch face goes from white-on-black to red (screenshot).

[image: wake watch face emulator]

It then says:

> Long press or click &" hold on the watch face of your device or emulator.

When I press on the watch face it does not do anything. I have tried pressing with the mouse, as well as using the touchscreen on my laptop.

How do I open the watch faces list?

I am on Arch Linux, Android Studio (beta) 2021.01, WearOS Round API 30.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of clicking on an empty area on the watch face (as I was doing), you are supposed to click on the clock area of the watch face (using the mouse or the touchscreen), marked in green in the screenshot.

[image: clock area on watch face]

This opens up the watch faces list successfully.

[image: watch faces list]